# create a System Dashboard in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to create a system view in Dynamics. I have followed the steps they share in Microsoft foro here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/create-edit-dashboards#create-a-new-dashboard

Create a new dashboard

1. Open solution explorer, and then select Components > Dashboards.
2. Select New, choose a layout, and then select Create.
3. LIn the Dashboard: New dialog box enter a name for the dashboard.
4. Select one of the component areas and then select the icon for a
   chart or a list.
5. You can have up to six components in the dashboard.
6. When you are finished adding components to your dashboard, select
   Save and then Publish.

Issue is that once is plublished and saved, it does not appear on the dropdown list of my systems dashboards.  Any tip why?

Thanks,

Comment: I remember I faced this issue in the past. Sometimes creating another test dashboard will flush both customizations, not sure if it is cache issue. try this and let us know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first , Please make sure that you enable the dashboard for everyone.

if still not able to see the dashboard, please follow the steps below to enable the dashboard for the App that you use:

1- From Settings go to Customizations.

2- Click on Customize the System.

3- under the Components, click on Apps.

4- Open the App that you need to show the dashboard on.

5- From Dashboards, select the dashboard that you need to show.
[image]
6- Save, close, and then publish all customizations.